# Extracting ARIMA coefficients for use in custom function

Tags: r, function, panel, autoregressive-models

I want to run a customized function based on ARIMA model. The function calls the ma3 coefficient from ARIMA (2, 0, 3) model ran on daily data of a year and subtracts ma3 coefficient from 2, for every firm. I have 5 years daily data for five firms, so each firm should have 5 year-wise values. My code:

```
>Stressy =function(x) 2-summary(arima(x, order=c(2,0,3)))$coefficients[1, "ma3"] 
>Funny = aggregate(cbind(QQ) ~  Year + Firm , df, FUN = Stressy)
```

Running my code gives the following error:

```
Error in summary(arima(x, order = c(2, 0, 3)))$coefficients : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I know the result can be estimated manually but my data set is large enough to be confusing when handled manually. Please suggest an edit to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you could get the ma3 coefficient:

```
Stressy <- function(x) 2-coef(arima(x, order=c(2,0,3)))["ma3"]
```

or

```
Stressy <- function(x) 2-arima(x, order=c(2,0,3))$coef["ma3"]
```

Your original custom function didn't work because `summary(arima_object)` gives you a table, to which you cannot apply the `$` operator:

```
x <- arima(df, c(2,0,3))
class(summary(x))
[1] "summaryDefault" "table"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user5042861 . It worked exactly as required.